# replication over internet- sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, merge-replication

I'm having trouble configuring merge replication over untrusted domains.

I have a remote `serverA` which has a real IP and I configured this server to be his own distributor and publisher and also a ftp-server for the snapshot folder to be shared. I created a windows login which has the sysadmin permission and has users having the db_owner role on both the replicated Database and distribution database and the merge PAL role and the sql-server agent is log on as this windows login and also this login is the job owner for all the jobs that is on the distribution.

And my local serverB is the subscriber server doesn't have a static IP. I configured this server to be the subscriber and to get the snapshot folder from ftp server.

At the distributor, the jobs are running with success, but at the subscriber the job always failing.

When i view the job history, it says job failed. When i view synchronization status it says the process can't connect to the distributor.

When i launched the replication monitor, I found two messages:

1. Schema script couldn't be propagated to the subscriber
2. The process couldn't connect to ftpsite using port 2015.

Could someone please help me with this?